# SQL Script Execution using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I am using Invoke-Sqlcmd to execute the SQL file in database in Powershell. This SQL files is having some SQL Procedures like "USP_UpdateUsers @sss" and some direct queries like "Insert into table ...."
What I need - when this sql file executes using Powershell then Procedures should execute sucessfully but the direct queries like "Insert into table ...." should not be executed, it should give errors.

SQL roles can be created only for SQL procedure execution but I don't want any separate SQL roles for this execution.
Please let me know Is there any way to handle this situation using Invoke-Sqlcmd?

I am using this line of code

```
 Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $db3 -InputFile $_.FullName -username $username -password $password -verbose *> $outputFileName
```

Comment: Simple: don't execute such an SQL file that contains insert statements. For more serious a note, what you are asking is a bit strange. [Edit] the question and explain with more details what's the [case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) you are trying to solve. Are you running user-supplied scripts? Why not use roles?

Comment: Many people will use this utility - "This power shell script to be executed at a fixed interval - in which people will place a SQL file in a folder. This utility will pick the file and execute the sql files procedures in database". If someone place any direct sql query like insert/update/delete in SQL file then this will also be executed in database. This needs to be avoided.

Comment: For SQL User Roles, we are not the administrators that's why separate role can't be created.

Comment: @vonPryz Hope, now the ask is clear :)

Comment: This sounds like a very bad idea as it is a big *security risk*! Either by a bug or by malicious action, what if there's a `delete` or `truncate` statement? Surely you don't want to execute those either? Please, _talk with your DBA_ about this scenario and ask for solution that the DBA supports.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you are fine for creating role, after discussion with DBA:

For restricting the users not to execute the statements, you can do following steps:

1. First create role, which will be used for executing the scripts

```sql
CREATE ROLE ScriptExecutor;
```

2. Now, assign the permissions to the role. The specific permissions you want to grant to the user.

```sql
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO ScriptExecutor
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO ScriptExecutor
```

3. Now, the user, who is going to execute the script, should be added to role.

```sql
ALTER ROLE ScriptExecutor ADD MEMBER UserName
```

4. Now, this user can be used to execute the powershell script. Now this user will not be able to perform INSERT statements.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $db3 -InputFile $_.FullName -username $username -password $password -verbose *> $outputFileName
```

#### If you don't want to create SQL role:

You can have a powershell script, which loops through the SQL files and only executes the file if there are no `INSERT` statments. You can extrapolate to satisfy further DML statements like `DELETE`, `UPDATE`.

```bsh
foreach($file in Get-childitem C:\dev -Filter *.sql)
{

    if((select-string -Path $file -Pattern "INSERT") -ne $null)
    {
         "The file $file contains INSERT Statement. So, will not be executed" | out-File $outputFileName -Append
    }
    else
    {

    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $db3 -InputFile $File -username $username -password $password -verbose *> $outputFileName

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Did you notice the `I don't want any separate SQL roles` part in the question? Not that it's sensible, but this answer contradicts that requirement.

Comment: @vonPryz, Sorry. I missed to notice that part. I will update my answer.